# Using require in a module -- Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, module, require

This seems fairly trivial but is giving me hella grief!

I have a module in the lib folder.

```
require 'net/http'
module Weather

  def get_response
    NET::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse 'someURL').body
  end

end
```

The controller.

```
class SunController < ApplicationController
include Weather

  def show  
    logger.debug get_response
  end
end
```

config/Application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

And I get this error

```
uninitialized constant Weather::NET
```

I know the module is loaded correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: don't define `lib` explicitly in your autoload paths.  It will be loaded when the application starts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class is `Net::HTTP` not `NET::HTTP`.